# How to open new window/tab but focus on opener window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, new-window

I want to emulate the ctrl + click interaction to open a link in a background tab across all browsers.

The slight different is that the link is based on a checkbox being checked.

Here is the JSbin + the code for the question for future reference:

**JSBin link**

http://jsbin.com/hisozawibu/2/

**Code**

```
<input class="ad-check" data-url="http://www.google.com" type="checkbox" id="test" name="test" />
<label for="test">Test</label>

$('body').on('click', '.ad-check' ,function(){
    var self = $(this);
    window.open(self.attr('data-url'), "_blank");
    window.blur();
});
```

I have looked at libraries, but it seem unnecessary for something so simple.

The technique I want to acheive, can be seen here on Kayak, when you search for hotels and select a provider.

http://www.kayak.co.uk/hotels

B

Comment: why do u mean by background??

Comment: The tab doesn't take focus.

Comment: It replicates the approach of ctrl and click with the mouse on a link.

Comment: Open new window, focus on current window

Comment: Open New Tab, focus on current tab. If it is only possible with new window though, that would be just as useful

Comment: Only thing that seems to work is the following; https://github.com/hpbuniat/jquery-popunder.

Comment: This seems far to heavy though considering what it is required to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, Utilizing this http://jsfiddle.net/azproduction/LRc7Z/ pattern

Try

html

```
<input class="ad-check" data-url="http://www.google.com" type="checkbox" id="test" name="test" />
<label for="test">Test</label>
<a id="ad-check-link" href=""></a>
```

js

```
var simulateClick = function (ctrl, shift, isMiddle) {
    var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    evt.initMouseEvent('click'
                       , true, true, window
                       , 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ctrl
                       , false, shift, false
                       , isMiddle ? 1 : 0, null );
    document.getElementById('ad-check-link').dispatchEvent(evt);
};
// substituted `.one()` for `.on()` to prevent calling action
// if clicked second time, after being initially checked by first click
$('body').one('click', '.ad-check' ,function(){
    var self = $(this);
    var link = $("a#ad-check-link")
               .prop("href", self.attr('data-url'))[0];

    link.onclick = simulateClick(true, false, false);
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/awjvbLt5/1/

Comment: One thing - How do you do this with multiple checkboxes?

Comment: @PI. For multiple checkboxes , could call `.each()` on `input.ad-check` elements , utilize `name` or other attribute for `id`'s of `a` elements ; pass attribute as element `id` parameter for `simulateClick`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need.

http://jsfiddle.net/5fz2u6Lq/

```
$('body').on('click', '.ad-check' ,function(){
    var self = $(this);
    var win = window.open(self.attr('data-url'), "_blank", 'modal=yes');
    win.blur();
});
```

**Edit :**

What if you also focus the old one.

http://jsfiddle.net/5fz2u6Lq/1/

```
$('body').on('click', '.ad-check' ,function(){
    var self = $(this);
    var current = window;
    var win = window.open(self.attr('data-url'), "_blank", "modal=yes");
    win.blur();
   current.focus();

});
```

Comment: That isn't what I need, that opens a new window and gives focus to the new window. That is no different from what I provided apart from it is a new window, and not a tab

Comment: It does not give the focus to the new window ... i'm using IE9 and it work. You want new tab without focus ?

Comment: That isn't the behaviour in Chrome.

Comment: You want new tab without focus or new window ?

Comment: Either is fine, but it has to work cross browser. This seems to be the only solution currently - https://github.com/hpbuniat/jquery-popunder

Comment: Seems on the heavy side for what it provides you though, seems like UA detection is required because of browser inconsistencies

Comment: I edited my answer. Try to focus on the old one. I don't have chrome install at work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63943/discussion-between-pi-and-mathieu-labrie-parent).