# Open a new tab but focus should remain on same page using typescript/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, browser

We have a link and by pressing the ctrl key if we click that link, that should open a new tab, but we want our focus should be on the main screen (current screen).

We have tried various suggested options, like:

```
var currentWindow = window;

var newWindow = window.open("", "_blank");
newWindow.location = `/dashboard/agency/${c.id}`;
newWindow.blur();

currentWindow.focus();
```

but nothing is working fine, and on clicking, this link in opening up in a new tab, and control also goes to that tab, instead to stay on the current screen. Any thoughts?

Comment: see: [How to open new window/tab but focus on opener window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26656809/how-to-open-new-window-tab-but-focus-on-opener-window)